# How can I get all the tags on Stack Overflow by using Stack Exchange API

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, api

I try it on this site:https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags, but it only return a little part of them, and there is some filed that I can't understand in the json result:

"has_more": true,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9983,
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 30,
  "total": 44464,
  "type": "tag"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initially you only get the results on page 1. For every next page, you need to pass in the page parameter.

The next url is:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page=2&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow
```

Make sure to check on `has_more` before trying to read the next page.